# Laravel Nova how to add a live counter to text field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using the `Nova` Admin panel for my `Laravel` application.

I have defined and added a new resource where the admin is supposed to fill out some text fields. One of those fields is a meta-title eg. meta description. So far so good, but I want to add a live counter to show the length of the string which is been entered to the textfield.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GluePear basically I have just created the Nova resources and defined the fields, which now are visible in the backend eg. the nova admin panel

Answer (score 0):

There is a ext package that make this possible, i don't know if I can post this here with link. But if you search "Charcounter" as novapackage you find it.

Comment: Hmm not exactly what I was looking for but this could work... I'm more looking for something like the counter in the `yoast` plugin for `wordpress`